# "I close, therefore I am"

Tags: idiom

In response to an SE close voter's (what I perceive to be) shifting justification for voting to close a question, I wrote:

> ...and whenever I see someone's close reason evolve and morph during a discussion... well... I assume "[I close therefore I am.](https://www.britannica.com/topic/cogito-ergo-sum)" is at play.

where I link to the famous *cogito, ergo sum*.

Closing a question literally prevents answer posts. It stops the conversation, stops the discourse. It can be seen to end a discussion or squelch a debate, or even "end the party" (i.e. a "party-pooper").

I'm making a [phrase-request](/questions/tagged/phrase-request). What would be a phrase similar to *cogito, ergo sum* that would match the sense that I've described above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few different options, as [Smith's shows](https://archive.org/details/copiouscriticale00smit/page/126/mode/2up), including *claudo* (the origin of the English "close"), [*praecludo*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpraecludo) (not mentioned in Smith's here) and *operio*, which is often used of gates and doors, especially in Roman comedy.

Of three, I'd recommend *praecludo* here which is more often used for putting an end to something (which "closing a thread" would imply). You have a decently close analog with Suetonius' *[Nero] praeclusit cunctos negotiatores*, "he shut down all the merchants (= he closed all the merchants' businesses)."

The issue though is that Latin, like the English you provided, really does demand an object. It feels weird in both languages because the verb is transitive. The object could be as simple as *id* or *hoc* if you're referring to the discussion at hand, which also might be the clearest way to refer to things. If you're in a different thread or chatting elsewhere, you might also want to use *illud*, which emphasizes the distance (while *hoc* would refer to the discussion at hand). You could also say *sermonem*, which, while often refers to "speech" (as in language, spoken speech), can refer to conversations, discourse, and discussions, too.

Putting that all together, you get something like:

> **[id/hoc/illud] praecludo ergo sum.**